# Can't boot Windows 7 after runing ubuntu from flash drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb

I have been trying out using a usb to boot lunix and it worked but now I can not boot into windows 7 it gives me the error "This is not a bootable disk Please insert a floppy and press any key..."

I have tried changing the boot priority, and removing all usb devices and drives. If try install ubuntu from the toolbar it doesn't even recognize there is an OS anymore but it did before.

I used the Boot-repair as recommended and it gave me the following report

http://paste.ubuntu.com/11614374/

I am new to Ubuntu and have no experience with creating/editing editing or working with bootloaders so please be detailed in your response, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you have your original Windows CD or a bootable Windows USB drive, boot from that.  It will give you the option to try to repair your installation.